# What is this shape called?

Tags: terminology, analytic-geometry, 3d

I've encountered an unusual shape that I have no idea the name of. We have a sticker on the shape that tells us the equation $z^2 = \frac{x^2}{a^2-y^2}$

Here is a picture of the shape itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dCJr.jpg

edit: i realized it might be a bit tough from just one angle so here is a second picture 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FibB.jpg

Comment: Not every shape has a name, because there are more possible shapes than names. You could call this one a "toothpaste tube", circular on one end and flat on the other.

Comment: Is it similar to this shape? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/783408/117057

Comment: @shoover quite similar except that it doesn't flat when reaching the bottom of the shape. It's quite smooth.

Comment: @rahul well that's quite a predicament since we want to label our 3d models with names of the shapes. I'll see what my supervisor wants to do

Comment: It sure does look like that circle-triangle-square thing, or at the very least circle-triangle-rectangle. Here's another example: http://kitwallace.tumblr.com/post/103975175234/george-harts-circle-triangle-square-puzzle

Comment: And another MSE question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/896725/117057

Answer (score 1):

On the tumblr link above, it's called a wedge-shaped cylinder.  Interestingly, this shape is talked about on p. 222-225 of *Magnificent Mistakes in Mathematics* by Posamentier and Lehmann, 2013.  They don't provide a specific name for the shape though.[image: wedge-shaped cylinder].